# Write a batch file that starts a java program

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, batch-processing

So I have a java project with multiple java files.

I know that is almost straight forward to start a java application using batch file. But that is for a pretty simple java program with a single class.

However I am wondering if it is possible to do that with in a scale of a project that you usually create using eclipse. A large project with multiple packages, classes and multiple java files.

My try was to write a script and apply on the main class as following

```
set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin

javac -classpath twitter/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar;twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar" sourcepath="lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar;lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar;lib/twitter4j-stream-4.0.1.jar;svm_light_lib Program.java

java Program
```

However when I start the .bat file it automatically closes.
Any Ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: open a command line window, and launch it from there, and you'll have an error message. Don't double-click it in Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

- First, never overwrite the [environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `path`, not even
  temporarily. Append your folder instead: `set "path=%path%;%mypath%"` or `set "path=%mypath%;%path%"`.
- ([There exists a particular `path` command](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) but I'm not sure about right syntax: `path=%path%;%mypath%` with `=` assignment or `path %path%;%mypath%` without it).
- Use full path to a program if you know it, e.g. `"%mypath%\javac"`.
- For better readability, values for `-classpath` and `-sourcepath` options are stored to the [environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) `mycpth` and  `mysrcp`, respectively. Note and use proper `"` quotation and no spacing around `=` to avoid any leading and trailing spaces in all `set` commands.
- `pause` to see all the `javac` output. [Displays the message](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) `Press any key to continue . . .`

Next code should be (syntax) error-free. However, success depends (among others) on *classpath* and *sourcepath* entries visibility as well...

```
set "mypath=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin"
set "path=%path%;%mypath%"
set "mycpth=twitter/twitter4j-stream-3.0.5.jar;twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar"
set "mysrcp=lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar;lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar;lib/twitter4j-stream-4.0.1.jar;svm_light_lib"

"%mypath%\javac" -classpath "%mycpth%" -sourcepath "%mysrcp%" Program.java
pause
java Program
```

Answer (score 0):

> However I am wondering if it is possible to do that with in a scale of a project that you usually create using eclipse. A large project with multiple packages, classes and multiple java files.

Of course it is possible!

In this case, I suspect the problem is that you `java` command doesn't have a "-cp" argument.  The `java` command is probably failing because it can't find twitter classes ... at runtime.

Remember to include "." on the classpath ... or else `java` won't find the file that you just compiled.

@JB Nizet's suggestion is also very important advice for finding out what is actually happening.

Comment: I am not sure I got what you mean to include "." on the classpath ... you mean to add the "dot" and where to add it ?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) If you understand how classpaths work, you should be able to answer that for yourself. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: 2a) It probably doesn't matter so long as the `java` and `javac` classpaths are consistent.